# How to mock default package in dependency with Jest?

Tags: jestjs, commonjs

My dependency includes `os` and `fs` with `require`. I didn't notice any issues with my unit tests until I ran in a Jenkins env which gave this error:

`StorageDirectoryResolutionError: Storage directory resolution failedUnsupportedFilePlatform: Platform not supported for file operations`

I updated my Jest config to be like this:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^os$': '<rootDir>/tests/dependency-mocks/os.js',
    '^fs$': '<rootDir>/tests/dependency-mocks/fs.js',
  },
```

I am mocking `os` and `fs`, even though error is around `fs`, to ensure things are same between my machine and Jenkins.

My `os.js` is tiny:

```js
module.exports = {
  homedir: () => '/user/home',
  platform: () => 'darwin',
  release: () => 'some release',
};
```

I have an `os.ts` file in `__mocks__` like this:

```js
export default {
  homedir: () => '/user/home',
  platform: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('darwin'),
  release: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('some release'),
};
```

My actual file has this issue:

```js
const os = require('os');
console.log(os); // my exported object is on a default key
```

```
 { default:
       { homedir: [Function: homedir],
         platform:
          { [Function: mockConstructor]
            _isMockFunction: true,
            getMockImplementation: [Function],
            mock: [Getter/Setter],
            mockClear: [Function],
            mockReset: [Function],
            mockRestore: [Function],
            mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
            mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
            mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
            mockReturnValue: [Function],
            mockResolvedValue: [Function],
            mockRejectedValue: [Function],
            mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
            mockImplementation: [Function],
            mockReturnThis: [Function],
            mockName: [Function],
            getMockName: [Function] },
         release:
          { [Function: mockConstructor]
            _isMockFunction: true,
            getMockImplementation: [Function],
            mock: [Getter/Setter],
            mockClear: [Function],
            mockReset: [Function],
            mockRestore: [Function],
            mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
            mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
            mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
            mockReturnValue: [Function],
            mockResolvedValue: [Function],
            mockRejectedValue: [Function],
            mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
            mockImplementation: [Function],
            mockReturnThis: [Function],
            mockName: [Function],
            getMockName: [Function] } } }
```

This is where it gets very weird. If I do NOT use `moduleNameMapper`, the dependency does NOT use my mock file. When I do use `moduleNameMapper` it ignores the `.js` file for `moduleNameMapper` and goes to my `.ts` file in `__mocks__`. I realized this when I added a random key to the mock and saw the update in console log.

I need the dependency to use `os.release()` without the object being nested within `default`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was really simple. Changed `export default {}` in mock files to `module.exports = {}`.

My project uses `import/export` for nearly everything. Due to the system it runs on, we have to use `const fs = require('fs')` instead of `import fs from 'fs';` The mocks using `export` had no issue until `moduleNameMapper` got thrown into the mix.